# How to add boolean column into resultset in java then add result to jtable

Tags: java, jtable, resultset

let me explain what i  trying to achieve here 
in my result set their are data with 4 columns  then i need to add 1 more column manually and it's should contain  boolean  values (false)

```
 ResultSet res = DbConnect.tabelDb(sql); // get result set 
List expRptColWise = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 1; i <= res.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
    expRxptColWise.add(false);
}

attendence.tblA.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(res))
```

i have try this code  found in  stackoverflow.com
 still this make no changes to my j table it only show 4 columns only

Comment: Can't be using `DBUtils`...you'll need to make the effort to manually process the `ResultSet` yourself

Comment: your are suggesting  override the tablemodel

Comment: I'm suggesting creating your own and filling it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it can be done using `DBUtils.resultSetToTableModel` as it's actual `TableModel` implementation is unknown, instead, you're going to have to get hands dirty, for example...

```
try (ResultSet rs = ...) {
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    for (int col = 0; col < rsmd.getColumnCount(); col++) {
        model.addColumn(rsmd.getColumnName(col + 1));
    }
    model.addColumn("boolean column");

    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector data = new Vector();
        for (int col = 0; col < rsmd.getColumnCount(); col++) {
            data.add(rs.getObject(col + 1));
        }
        data.add(Boolean.FALSE);
        model.addRow(data);
    }

}
```

Remember, if you open a resource, you should close it, see [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

Comment: now here your code work perfectly and  now i need to know  more .how to add check box like this .how to convert this new column to checkbox column

Comment: The `JTable` should do this automatically, so long as you are using `Boolean` as the columns value and not `boolean`

Comment: this really help to me more than you  think so i really appreciate this your  help here. i have add the model to JTable but when i run programme  the 5 th column is show only text like false so that the problem so far i have try this many time and many examples but i couldn't able add check box to fifth column. here clearly need to add result and checkbox relative to  each row  data that get from result set ____thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                 for (int col = 0; col < rsmd.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                             model.addColumn(rsmd.getColumnName(col + 1));
                            }
                             model.addColumn("boolean");

                 while (rs.next()) {
                            Vector data = new Vector();
                            for (int col = 0; col < rsmd.getColumnCount(); col++) {//add another Column
                                        data.add(rs.getObject(col + 1));
                                    }
                                             data.add( Boolean.FALSE);
                                             model.addRow(data);
}


        JTable newOne=new JTable(model);


            JFrame f=new JFrame();
                f.add(new JScrollPane( newOne));
             f.pack();
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         f.setVisible(true);
```